# SAS - Loop through data

Tags: sas

I have a dataset in the following format :

```
Date            Item            Customer          Qty
```

`10/05/2017      HDD              IGM                     1
10/09/2017       Mouse           DCD                      4
10/11/2017       Mouse           IGM                      1`

Assuming that the data is sorted by the **Date**, I want SAS to loop through each record and look back 6 weeks to see whether a customer is a **Repeat** customer or a **New** customer.

My final result would look like this :

```
Date            Item            Customer          Qty           Repeat Flag
```

`10/05/2017      HDD              IGM                     1            0
10/09/2017       Mouse           DCD                      4            0
10/11/2017       Mouse           IGM                      1            1`

I am new to SAS and have been stuck here for a while. Thanks in advance.

Edit - I know this can be done using ProcSQL but I'm trying to implement it using the SAS language only.

Comment: What do you mean by "look back 6 weeks"?  Do you want to consider customers whose last record was more than 6 weeks ago as NEW?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort the data by customer and date.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  by customer date ;
  lag_date=lag(date);
  if first.customer then lag_date=.;
  new = lag_date < intnx('week',date,-6,'s');
run;
```

Comment: The missing lag_date on the first record will evaluate `new` as true. `new = . < lag_date < intnx('week',date,-6,'s');`

Comment: @chris  Right. So someone with no prior dates with be considered a new customer.

Comment: Thanks guys! This is exactly what I wanted to do. Works like a charm. I'd never used the interval functions in SAS so this helps a lot.